# Как получить доступ к элементу background?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Добрый день, подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно решить следующую задачу.

Есть список `<li>`, к каждому элементу которого требуется вывести опцию управления в виде кнопки, нажатие на которую отображает другой список (удалить, скрыть и т.д.).

В качестве «кнопки» для вывода второго списка использую изображение, загруженное как `background: url(img.png)` для каждого элемента `<li>`.

Проблема — не могу получить какой-либо доступ (например, `hover()` ) к изображению img.png (для смены курсора и дальнейшей обработки клика). Решаема ли вообще задача получения доступа к background ?

Comment: `$li.css('background', 'new-image.png');`. Вот если он у вас в `:after`, то там действительно не знаю как действовать не через css. В принципе, все это нужно делать через `:hover` и `:active`, и проблем быть не должно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Взаимодействовать можно только с **HTML-элементами**, а не с их свойствами. 
Тут *background-image* - это свойство, и как бы вы не кликали по фоновой картинке, клик будет срабатывать именно на **элементе**, у которого эта фоновая картина. Более того, даже доступа к псевдоэлементам нет. Поэтому либо делайте картинку отдельным элементом, либо вешайте клик на весь `<li>`

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант, добавляйте в ваш `li` `div` у которого будет фоновое изображение и реагируйте на события связанные с этим `div`